# Debugging .NET Core projects AND .NET libraries available in NuGet

Tags: docker, nuget, .net-core

I have a .NET Core console app and a .NET Standard library. The app consumes the library via a nuget source in RELEASE, and a project reference in DEBUG, via a `Condition` on each `ItemGroup`.

This is working great locally, as I can make changes and test both the library and the app in parallel. When the sources get committed (obviously the library before the app), the library gets published, and the app consumes the published package.

Now, this app is also one piece of a docker-compose, and I want to be able to debug while running in Docker. This is perfectly supported with Visual Studio, but it also means my app is built against the library package available in my nuget source, not a locally-compiled and debuggable one.

I do have clues as to how to work around this, but would like to know if I'm just not either missing something, or trying to reinvent the wheel (though I really like new wheels).

1. I could copy the library's sources and project as part of the Dockerfile, and make sure it respects the `Condition` within my app's csproj. This sounds patchy.
2. I could have a local folder within the app sources where I copy the freshly built library's .nupkg, which would be copied via Dockerfile before `dotnet restore`, and also mentioned in the Nuget.Config, but ignored in .gitignore.

I'm about to try #2. Is there a simpler approach?

Thanks.